# Flask running on port 5000 on Google App engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

When running flask app on google app engine , it throws me an error that I have to serve my app on port 8080.
So I specified the port in

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080)
```

But on running it on App engine it shows that my app is still serving on https://127.0.0.1:5000

EDIT : I got confused somewhere on running the app,  so I tried running the app locally using `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` ( this throws an error)
On running `dev_appserver.py ./` runs the server , but I the page at `localhost:8080` is blank , And I get an error in the terminal that it was unable to import python modules even though I have made a `appengine_config.py` script and a lib subfolder with all the python packages downloaded to it.

My project structure is :

`root/
-app.py
--lib/
--static/
--templates/
-app.yaml
-appengine_config.py`

**EDIT** : The server seems to be running fine now , but it is still unable to import python packages (  I have them installed in the lib folder , also I have used the sys hack ) Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/padam/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/padam/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/padam/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/padam/Documents/git/gae-fumen/app.py", line 4
    from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
       ^
```

How do I fix it ?

Comment: You need to stop your running server before restarting it…

Comment: Assuming you are developing for the standard environment, you may also want to look at the official Hello World repo - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/flask/hello_world

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I did

Comment: @alpeware I did follow that , in that they do not specify

`if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080)`

I also tried without using the above code , it still served on 5000

Comment: what's the entry in your `app.yaml`? how are you starting the app?

Comment: @JeffreyGodwyll I am runnnig it under development so I used  `python app.py`

Comment: and the contents of your `app.yaml`? You make mention of errors when running with the `dev_appserver`. What are those?

Comment: @JeffreyGodwyll Contents of app.yaml 

`# Config file for Google APp Engine
entrypoint: python app.py
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
    
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: app.py
- url: /static
  static_dir: static`

I tried adding the libraries paramete , but it would give error no module named <python-package>

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're on the flexible runtime, to run standard app engine apps locally, you need to use the `dev_appserver`. In the root of your project you could run `dev_appserver.py .`.

With an `app.py` with the following minimum content:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# define a few routes here or in app.yaml

@app.route('/')
def home():
    """Root page"""
    return 'home'
```

You then define how to start your flask application in your project's `app.yaml`'s handlers section:

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: app.app  # a reference to your app object defined in app.py
```

That should get the app engine setup out of the way.
More info on getting started with app engine and flask in the following repo: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/flask/hello_world

---

EDIT:
Read more about which environment to run on [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/)

The contents of your `app.yaml` indicate you're using the [flexible runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/). Such as `runtime: python` and `entrypoint:...`. If you want to stick with the flexible runtime, that's fine. You'll first have to install your dependencies locally. The preferred method being a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

If what you want is [app engine standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime), based on your file/folder layout, the structure of your `app.yaml` will be something close to :

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: app.app
```

With app engine standard, to use flask you'll then install with `pip install flask -t lib` to install flask into your lib folder before running the app with `dev_appserver.py`

Comment: Hey thanks , now it just seems to run , but I am still unable to use python packages .

Comment: **EDIT:**
Hey thanks , now it just seems to run , but I am still unable to use python packages . Should `app.yaml` include 

`libraries` 
I tried specifying the libs but it gives me this 
`google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: the library "flask" is not supported
  in "./app.yaml", line 11, column 1`

Comment: flask isn't an inbuilt 3rd party library & if on standard, you install the dependencies into your lib folder added to your app via vendoring, `pip install flask -t lib`. If on flex, you install flask into your virtualenv for local use but declare it in a `requirements.txt` to picked up by the runtime when deploying to production

Comment: I did that I have all the packages installed in the Lib folder , I have even specified libraries parameter in app.yaml .

Comment: Hey , I tried your method , the server seems to be running , but it is unable to import python packages , here's the error:
P.S the main question

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate `config.py` file to config your database and port settings like,

```
DEBUG = True
PORT = 8000
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
SECRET_KEY = "SOME SECRET"
```

Now create one more separate file `app.py` and write below code,

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app('config')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host=app.config['HOST'],
                port=app.config['PORT'],
                debug=app.config['DEBUG'])
```

It should work.

Comment: That's definitely more configurable, but logically the code is pretty much the same as in the question.

Comment: As @AdamByrtek said , both are logically the same , but I'll still try it

Comment: Tried it still getting the same output

`* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 122-141-330`